# Laravel eloquent not calling the relationship (returning string)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have this relationship:

A store may have many products and each products can have many effects

`stores` and `products` -> many to many relationship

`products` and `effects` -> one to many (one product can have multiple effects)

Here are my relationships:

**Store model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product');
}
```

**Product model**

```
public function stores()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Store');
}

public function effects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Effect');
}
```

**Effect model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
}
```

Now, I can access the relationship with products ok, but when I access the effects relationships:

```
    $store = Store::where('slug', 'cantina')->first();
    dd($store->products->first()->effects);
```

The dd returns a string with the name of the relationship:

```
"effects"
```

I never seen this "error" before, anyone knows why the relationship are returning a string instead of the eloquent?

**[Edit]**

If I digit anything in the relationship call, they output what I digited:

```
dd($store->products->first()->effects);
//Output:
"effects"
```

Another example:

```
dd($store->products->first()->foobar);
//Output:
"foobar"
```

Comment: So the relation is store has multiple products and products can have multiple effects?

Comment: This is very strange behaviour. Aren't you overriding Eloquent in any way, whether manually or via traits or by extending something other than Eloquent directly? Look for overrides on the `__get` magic method, perhaps? Post your model's code if you need a hand identifying this.

Comment: Hey @TomasButeler, your reply helped me to resolve my problem, My model were with a wrong acessor, and because of that, is returning a string. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you have time, please post (and accept) an answer detailing what it was you were doing wrong.

Comment: Yep, I'll do it tomorrow!